# Does PicoBlaze have separate flags for each regbank (like Z80), or are the same flags used in both regbanks?

Tags: assembly, fpga, cpu-registers, picoblaze

Does PicoBlaze have separate flags for each regbank (like Z80), or are the same flags used in both regbanks? For instance, consider the following code:

```
regbank a
load s0, 0
sub  s0, 0
regbank b
load s0, 1
sub  s0, 0
regbank a
jump z , success
jump nz, failure
```

Where will it jump? To `success` or to `failure`?
In [my PicoBlaze Simulator](https://flatassembler.github.io/PicoBlaze/PicoBlaze.html) (it's runnable in a browser, try the "*Regbanks-Flags Test*" example, the 7th example from the left), it jumps to `success`. But I am not sure what it would do on real PicoBlaze.